# Where can I find the backlog of Bitcoin transactions?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

I would like to see and track the evolution of the backlog of Bitcoin transactions. Is there a website that does that?

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are some (in order of preference):

- https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#24h
- https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a place where I can see that on a graph over time?

Comment: @Hollossy https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#all